# How can I retrieve an array from a stack

Tags: c#

I would like to implement a stack in a project am working on, haven't used stacks before, as I am a beginner. I just felt like they would do the trick.
I got a general idea of how they work but am having troubles trying to retrieve an array that id have pushed into the stack, am returning

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        int G;
        int [] A=new int [2];
        Stack st = new Stack();

        for (G = 0; G < 5; G++)
        {
            A[0] = G;
            A[1] = G;


            st.Push(A);
        }

        foreach (Object obj in st)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Instead of getting a set of arrays, I am getting `System.Int32[]` - how can I return the contents of the array

Comment: `System.Int32[]` - that ***IS*** an array!

Comment: thanks marc maybe I was a little bit vague .. I would like to return the actual array  not a datatype

Comment: It's better practice to use the generic [`Stack<int []>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1) rather than the non-generic `Stack`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using

```
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

passing the object as an argument. This method expects a string as input, so you should convert your array in a string before.

This question may help you :
[int array to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822811/int-array-to-string)

This should work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        int G;
        int [] A=new int [2];
        Stack st = new Stack();

        for (G = 0; G < 5; G++)
        {
            A[0] = G;
            A[1] = G;


            st.Push(A);
        }

        foreach (Object obj in st)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", (int[])obj));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Also, you should notice that you are pushing the same array five times in the stack.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Fabio , Learnt something new , so I was pushing into the stack 5 times because I was just experimenting , anyways thanks again :)

Comment: Happy to help! Could you please accept my answer? thanks!